# Quiero que el nav quede seleccionado con un color al tocarlo

Tags: javascript, html, nav

Como dice en el título, quiero que el `nav` quede con un color al hacer clic, en el siguiente código de JavaScript pueden probar que si usando `querySelector` funciona pero solo con el primer LI "portafolio" del `nav` y yo quiero que funcione con todos por eso use luego `querySelectorAll` pero me tira error.

```js
let navcolor = document.querySelector(".cambiar-color");

navcolor.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>{
    navcolor.style="color:#ff3131";
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #1a1919;
    color: #F7F0F5;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#header__nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul id="header__nav">
            <li><a href="#portafolio" class="cambiar-color">Portafolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#habilidad" class="cambiar-color">Habilidades</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacto" class="cambiar-color">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En parte te respondiste solo. `querySelector` solo devuelve un elemento. Necesitas usar `querySelectorAll`, que devuelve una **lista** de elementos.

No se puede usar `addEventListener` sobre una lista. Es necesario recorrerla haciendo lo que fuese con cada elemento individualmente.

Estas listas se pueden recorrer como un arreglo (mediante `lista[posicion]`) o con `forEach`.

[Más información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```js
let navcolor = document.querySelectorAll(".cambiar-color")

navcolor.forEach(elemento => elemento.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>{
    elemento.style="color:#ff3131";
}))
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #1a1919;
    color: #F7F0F5;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#header__nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul id="header__nav">
            <li><a href="#portafolio" class="cambiar-color">Portafolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#habilidad" class="cambiar-color">Habilidades</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacto" class="cambiar-color">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```